# Ajax call using Breeze.js and angular $http

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs, breeze

I have intialized my service and wrote a method to make an ajax call using Breeze.js as the documentation say `setHttp($http)` is enough, but i wasn't able to make an ajax call.

```
breeze.NamingConvention.camelCase.setAsDefault();
factory.sample = function() {
   var serviceRoot = "";
   var serviceName = serviceRoot + '/sample/2787'; // sample GET URL
   new breeze.EntityManager(serviceName);

// use the current module's $http for ajax calls
   var ajax = breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance('ajax', 'angular');
   var data = ajax.setHttp($http);

   return data;
};
```

Could anyone hwel me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear for me what you want from your code sample. As I understand you want to make breeze use Angular's $http service to make ajax requests. Here is how it should be done:

```
var ajaxAdapter = breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance("ajax", "angular");
ajaxAdapter.setHttp($http);      
breeze.ajaxpost(ajaxAdapter);
```

> documentation say setHttp($http) is enough, but i wasn't able to make an ajax call.

Breeze is not supposed to make pure ajax calls. Use $http instead!

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear where you're doing this in your Angular app and whether you have properly injected the $http service.

As a general rule, it's good to always initialize the Breeze ajax adapter early in the app.run module like below.

```
angular.module('app').run(['$http', function($http) {
    // tell the adapter to use your app module's $http for ajax calls
    var ajax = breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance('ajax', 'angular');
    ajax.setHttp($http);
}]);
```

There is also a Breeze.Angular service that actually does the above configuration for you.

See the 'Use the AngularJS $http adapter' section at http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/customizing-ajax for more details.